# Flutter, flutter_inappwebview: Is there a way to set a timeout for page loads?

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I am using the flutter_inappwebview and would like to somehow react to page loads taking too long. I would like to set a timeout on every HTTP request performed by the web view (page loads, image loads, etc.) and when the request takes longer than X get informed so I can react to it in my app code.

I was not able to find something that would enable be to do that in the flutter_inappwebview API documentation.

Am I missing something? Is there a way?